# Dynamically loading assembly: why this code works?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, appdomain, .net-assembly

In my situation there are three components: `Consumer` class, `IExposedIface` interface and `Exposed` class implementing `IExposedIface`. Both `Consumer` and `Exposed` are linked statically with `IExposedIface`, but `Consumer` bears no compile-time reference to `Exposed`.

I am trying to come up with a scheme which would allow `Consumer` loading different versions of `Exposed` at runtime (depending on input data - let's say each input document carries an information about which version of `Exposed` should be used to process it). To achieve this, I started studying **AppDomains** and now I have a basic version working.

So far it seems to me there are two options when it comes to providing `IExposedIface` assembly to `Exposed` assembly.

1. Having `IExposedIface.dll` only in `Consumer`'s **bin** directory and handling `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event for the `AppDomain` in which I am creating an instance of `Exposed`
2. Having `IExposedIface.dll` both in `Consumer`'s **bin** directory as well as aside each `Exposed.dll`.

Now consider that I build `Exposed` against this `IExposedIface`:

```
public interface IExposedIface
{
    string SaySomething();    
}
```

and I build `Consumer` against this `IExposedIface`:

```
public interface IExposedIface
{
    string SaySomething();
    string SaySomethingDifferent();
}
```

In the first case, the exception

> Exception: **Method 'SaySomethingDifferent'** in type 'Exposed.Exposed' from
>       assembly 'Exposed, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' **does not have an implementation**.

is thrown in the moment I call `appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(...)` to create an instance of `Exposed` in the freshly created **AppDomain**.

That looks reasonable to me.

But in the second case, `appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(...)` goes through just fine and I can without problems call 'SaySomething()' method on the retrieved object. An exception

> **The method 'SaySomethingDifferent' was not found on the interface/type** 'IExposedIface.IExposedIface, IExposedIface, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

is only thrown when I actually call `SaySomethingDifferent()` in `Consumer`.

I was quite surprised that in this second case CLR had let me go so far...Could someone explain why this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Case #1 means that Exposed.dll is binding against the wrong version of IExposedIface.dll - the metadata loader is able to detect this when loading the assemblies because it finds an unimplemented interface method.
2. Case #2 (probably) means that you have the correct version of each IExposedIface.dll besides each Exposed.dll so each assembly can load within its own AppDomain. However AppDomain A has a different interface than AppDomain B which is only a problem when the call actually crosses the AppDomain border.

I'd suggest not trying those binary compatibility games and rather do proper versioning (ie. create a new interface with the new methods, inheriting from the old interface, so the new version of IExposedIface.dll is *really* backwards compatible). Anything else is *really* hard to debug because you can accidently end up loading *both* versions of IExposedIface.dll if they are reachable for windows, and then you have two versions of a Type in the AppDomain causing no end of trouble ;)